# Singular matrix error trying to simulate 3ph motor inverter

Tags: ltspice, inverter

I'm trying to simulate a high-power 3-phase motor inverter in LTspice, but I'm getting this singular matrix error and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried adding 1Meg of parallel resistance to the inductors and capacitors but that doesn't seem to help.

For now, I'm using a purely resistive load for the motor. Node 20, which the error message mentions, is the node connecting L1, C1 and R1.

The simulation runs fine without the LC-filter.

[image: LTspice circuit]

Here's the schematic: (Copy to text file als save as .asc file)

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1672 680
WIRE 320 -256 208 -256
WIRE 416 -256 384 -256
WIRE 800 -256 688 -256
WIRE 896 -256 864 -256
WIRE 1280 -256 1168 -256
WIRE 1376 -256 1344 -256
WIRE 112 -240 96 -240
WIRE 592 -240 576 -240
WIRE 1072 -240 1056 -240
WIRE 112 -224 112 -240
WIRE 128 -224 112 -224
WIRE 208 -224 208 -256
WIRE 208 -224 192 -224
WIRE 224 -224 208 -224
WIRE 320 -224 288 -224
WIRE 592 -224 592 -240
WIRE 608 -224 592 -224
WIRE 688 -224 688 -256
WIRE 688 -224 672 -224
WIRE 704 -224 688 -224
WIRE 800 -224 768 -224
WIRE 1072 -224 1072 -240
WIRE 1088 -224 1072 -224
WIRE 1168 -224 1168 -256
WIRE 1168 -224 1152 -224
WIRE 1184 -224 1168 -224
WIRE 1280 -224 1248 -224
WIRE 128 -192 112 -192
WIRE 208 -192 192 -192
WIRE 304 -192 288 -192
WIRE 608 -192 592 -192
WIRE 688 -192 672 -192
WIRE 784 -192 768 -192
WIRE 1088 -192 1072 -192
WIRE 1168 -192 1152 -192
WIRE 1264 -192 1248 -192
WIRE 112 -176 112 -192
WIRE 112 -176 96 -176
WIRE 304 -176 304 -192
WIRE 320 -176 304 -176
WIRE 416 -176 384 -176
WIRE 592 -176 592 -192
WIRE 592 -176 576 -176
WIRE 784 -176 784 -192
WIRE 800 -176 784 -176
WIRE 896 -176 864 -176
WIRE 1072 -176 1072 -192
WIRE 1072 -176 1056 -176
WIRE 1264 -176 1264 -192
WIRE 1280 -176 1264 -176
WIRE 1376 -176 1344 -176
WIRE 208 -144 208 -192
WIRE 320 -144 208 -144
WIRE 688 -144 688 -192
WIRE 800 -144 688 -144
WIRE 1168 -144 1168 -192
WIRE 1280 -144 1168 -144
WIRE 128 -64 -208 -64
WIRE 368 -64 128 -64
WIRE 608 -64 368 -64
WIRE 128 -32 128 -64
WIRE 368 -32 368 -64
WIRE 608 -32 608 -64
WIRE 1296 32 704 32
WIRE 1424 32 1376 32
WIRE -208 80 -208 -64
WIRE 128 80 128 48
WIRE 704 80 704 32
WIRE 704 80 128 80
WIRE 368 112 368 48
WIRE 1296 112 368 112
WIRE 1424 112 1424 32
WIRE 1424 112 1376 112
WIRE 608 144 608 48
WIRE 704 144 608 144
WIRE 128 176 128 80
WIRE 368 176 368 112
WIRE 608 176 608 144
WIRE 704 192 704 144
WIRE 1296 192 704 192
WIRE 1424 192 1424 112
WIRE 1424 192 1376 192
WIRE -208 288 -208 160
WIRE -48 288 -208 288
WIRE 128 288 128 256
WIRE 128 288 -48 288
WIRE 368 288 368 256
WIRE 368 288 128 288
WIRE 608 288 608 256
WIRE 608 288 368 288
WIRE -48 304 -48 288
FLAG -48 304 0
FLAG 128 80 L1
FLAG 368 112 L2
FLAG 608 144 L3
FLAG 80 -16 0
FLAG 320 -16 0
FLAG 560 -16 0
FLAG 560 192 0
FLAG 320 192 0
FLAG 80 192 0
FLAG 16 -240 0
FLAG 416 -256 A
FLAG 416 -176 _A
FLAG 16 -176 0
FLAG 896 -256 B
FLAG 896 -176 _B
FLAG 1376 -256 C
FLAG 1376 -176 _C
FLAG 80 32 A
FLAG 80 240 _A
FLAG 320 32 B
FLAG 320 240 _B
FLAG 560 32 C
FLAG 560 240 _C
FLAG 496 -240 0
FLAG 496 -176 0
FLAG 976 -240 0
FLAG 976 -176 0
SYMBOL voltage -208 64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 124 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName ACC
SYMATTR Value 580
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.5
SYMBOL sw 128 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1H
SYMBOL sw 128 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1L
SYMBOL sw 368 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName L2H
SYMBOL sw 368 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L2L
SYMBOL sw 608 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName L3H
SYMBOL sw 608 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName L3L
SYMBOL Digital\\diffschmitt 128 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -7 -16 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value vt=0 vh=0 Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL voltage 112 -240 R90
WINDOW 3 -48 168 Invisible 2
WINDOW 0 24 16 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 0.95 {motorFreq})
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL voltage 112 -176 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-1 1 {0/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} 0 {1/pwmFreq})
SYMBOL Digital\\and 256 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -40 114 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value td={pwmDeadTime} Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\and 352 -304 R0
WINDOW 3 -1 1 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMBOL Digital\\and 352 -224 R0
WINDOW 3 -31 117 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL Digital\\diffschmitt 608 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -7 -16 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value vt=0 vh=0 Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL Digital\\and 736 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -40 114 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value td={pwmDeadTime} Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL Digital\\and 832 -304 R0
WINDOW 3 -1 1 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A7
SYMBOL Digital\\and 832 -224 R0
WINDOW 3 -31 117 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A8
SYMBOL Digital\\diffschmitt 1088 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -7 -16 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value vt=0 vh=0 Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A9
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1216 -272 R0
WINDOW 3 -40 114 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value td={pwmDeadTime} Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A10
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1312 -304 R0
WINDOW 3 -1 1 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A11
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1312 -224 R0
WINDOW 3 -31 117 Invisible 2
SYMATTR Value tripdt=10n Vhigh=1
SYMATTR InstName A12
SYMBOL voltage 592 -240 R90
WINDOW 3 -48 168 Invisible 2
WINDOW 0 24 16 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 0.95 {motorFreq} 0 0 120)
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL voltage 592 -176 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-1 1 {0/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} 0 {1/pwmFreq})
SYMBOL voltage 1072 -240 R90
WINDOW 3 -48 168 Invisible 2
WINDOW 0 24 16 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 0.95 {motorFreq} 0 0 240)
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMBOL voltage 1072 -176 R90
WINDOW 0 -32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMATTR Value PULSE(-1 1 {0/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} {0.5/pwmFreq} 0 {1/pwmFreq})
SYMBOL res 1392 16 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL res 1392 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL res 1392 176 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10
TEXT -202 376 Left 2 !.tran 20ms
TEXT 48 304 Left 2 !.model SW SW(Ron=150m Roff=1G, Vt=0.5 Vh=-0.4)
TEXT -312 -136 Left 2 !.param pwmDeadTime=1us
TEXT -312 -200 Left 2 !.param motorFreq=50
TEXT -312 -168 Left 2 !.param pwmFreq=10k
TEXT 1224 -32 Left 2 ;Motor
RECTANGLE Normal 1216 -48 1456 240 2
```

Comment: Remove the lower part of the schematic and simulate just the control logic (those subcircuits with the gates). See if the problem persists.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine Thanks for looking into it. The simulation ran fine until I added the LC filters. Updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried to (a) add some resistance in series with the inductors and/or capacitors, (b) imbalance the load a bit, e.g. making R1=20. Does this change something?

Comment: Another attempt could be to connect the junction point of the caps to ground through a 10Meg resistor, maybe in parallel with a 10pF cap.

Comment: I already had some series resistance for the inductors (10m), adding some to the capacitors (10m) has fixed the error. The voltage between the motor phases looks fine, but there's +/-250MV on the phases relative to GND. Can you think of a way to fix that, or do you think I should ignore it?

Comment: Try modeling the parasitics as I told you in my last comment: connect a high value resistor in parallel with a small cap to ground. Maybe do this also for the node common to the motor windings. 10-100MOhm and/or 1-10pF should be ok. See if that helps.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine Adding 10pF and 10MOhm to the common of the LC filter and/or motor, the peaks at the motor phases to gnd have dropped to about 250kV, but there's a lot of ringing (~19MHz) and the simulation runs about 14x slower